# Allow SVG upload in EE

Tags: file-uploads

I'm trying to allow SVG uploads via the file fieldtype (EE 2.9.2), but it gives me an error:

> The file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

I have updated mimes.php with the following additions:

```
'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml',
'svg' => 'image/svg+xml'
```

but this has made no difference. I have also tried disabling XSS filtering in the EE CP - also does not work.

Finally, I added the following to config.php:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'svg';
```

And this does not work either. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The `svg` files is considered as `text/html` mime type by the `finfo_file()`.

So you need to set `Allowed File Types` as `All file types` inside `File Upload Preferences` to allow svg file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a .htaccess file with

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```